# IntelliJ Scala Case Class Autocompletion

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I must be missing something obvious here.  Why do I not get autocompletion for the parameters of the `Message` case class in IntelliJ?  I would expect to see a hint concerning the `text` parameter here.

[image]

Comment: Put the cursor between the parentheses and press Ctrl+P

Comment: Jesper - perfect!  might as well be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the cursor between the parentheses and press Ctrl+P.

Here is a handy [IntelliJ keyboard shortcuts](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) map (PDF), see the [Mac version](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf) if you use an Apple Mac.

Comment: You can also press CMD + SHIFT + A (at least on OSX, don't know if win/linux mapping matches) and type action's name (fuzzy search is supported) -- [mapping will be next to the name](http://take.ms/rx6ve). Hit enter and action will be triggered.